# Unable to Deallocating Memory in PowerShell 3.0 and 2.0

Tags: c#, powershell

A while back I wrote a simple full TCP connect scanner in C# and compiled that to a DLL. It spits out PSObjects to the pipeline to show the results of the scan. If I am scanning a CIDR /16 subnet, the amount of data I get back is well into the 512MiB according to Task Manager. I would like to find a way to deallocate this memory usage once I am done analyzing the results to free up space for other tasks (we have to work with less than 8 GiB of memory...). The problem is that I cannot get PowerShell to release it's hold on this memory. Does anyone know a good way to free up this memory consumption?

I've tried setting the variable to $null, Remove-Variable, and calling [GC]::Collect(), but the memory usage in Task Manager still remains at the same (or higher) levels. I am at a loss with this seemingly simple task. Maybe the memory is deallocated, but Task Manager just reports the previous allocation?

Answer (score 3):

The only deallocation of managed memory is going to be done by the CLR garbage collector.  Since you've already tried a GC collect, I'd say you have a managed memory hoard.  That is, you haven't found all of the roots that refer to your objects.  I suggest you use a tool like RedGate's Memory Profiler or the free ClrProfiler to determine what is still referencing the objects you have created.  I believe even Visual Studio 2013 has the ability to analyze managed memory from a dump file.  That may also help you find all objects holding a reference to your data objects. BTW do any of your objects wrap native resources (handles, memory, etc)?

Comment: That's just the thing, none of my objects wrap native or unsafe code... nor do I do any PInvoke, reading from buffers, or writing to buffers. There is almost nothing that can cause an overflow.